# How to check localStorage before ngResource makes a request?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

How can I check localStorage before `ngResource` makes a request? I would like my resource object to check local storage before I make a request to the server. I want to store my initial response from the server in local storage and then if the user reloads the page not have to make the request again and instead just pull it out of local storage.

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.factory('accountResource', function($resource) {

var entity = 'account';
var serverUrl = 'my/url/to/thing/';
var entityUrl = serverUrl + entity;
var resource = $resource(entityUrl + '/', {});

return {
  get: function() {

      //I am thinking about doing a check in here but wondered if there is a better way 
      return resource.get().$promise;
 }
};

});

}(angular));
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you have worked with so far please?

Comment: I added some of my code

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment you have left in the code is a good way to handle this:

```
get: function() {
    var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem('foo');

    return fromStorage ? fromStorage : resource.get().$promise;
 }
```

And then, in the resolve callback of your promise, you should store the value in localStorage.

Comment: I was thinking about handling it in there I just thought there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: You could create a service which will be a dependency of your accountResource that will check with a key if the value is present and you could reuse it accross your app, but you would still need to use it in your get method.

Comment: What is `resource` in `resource.get().$promise;`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess [angular-cache](http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/) shall be your best bet. Take a look at the [Using angular-cache with $http](http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/#using-angular-cache-with-http) section